# How to share a map across goroutines

Tags: go, concurrency, synchronization

I'm trying to code a notification struct in Go, that will hold a series of keys and their respective values, and will fire a notification if a value falls below a threshold.

the notification should fire only once, when the first sample falls below the threshold, and further samples below that should not fire again, UNTIL the value rises above the threshold.

for example, say my threshold is 10, and I send samples of 15, 14, 11, 10, ... 9. once 9 is sent, a notification should be fired. further samples of 8, 7, 4, should not cause any effect. following samples like 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 14, 30, should do nothing to. once a sample falls again below 10: 30, 20, 15, 10, 7... another notification must be sent.

I'm having a problem when multiple goroutines are manipulating my struct.

I tried syncrhonizing with a sync.Mutex, and ALSO use a sync.Map, but no luck. I'm feeling there is a reference copy or caching somewhere, but I'm too new in Go to find the problem.

for this, I created a struct like this:

```
type Notifier interface {
    Send(message string)
}

type NotificationBoard struct {
    mutex    sync.Mutex
    Last     sync.Map
    notifier Notifier
}

func (n *NotificationBoard) Init(notifier Notifier) {
    n.notifier = notifier
}

// NotifyLess ...
func (n *NotificationBoard) NotifyLess(key string, value, threshold float64) {
    n.mutex.Lock()
    defer n.mutex.Unlock()

    if value >= threshold {
        fmt.Printf("NotificationBoard.NotifyLess %v (value >= threshold): %v >= %v\n", key, value, threshold)
        n.Last.Store(key, value)
        return
    }

    // value < threshold
    if last, found := n.Last.Load(key); found == true {
        fmt.Printf("NotificationBoard.NotifyLess %v (value < threshold): %v < %v : found %v\n", key, value, threshold, last)
        if last.(float64) >= threshold { // first trigger
            n.notifier.Send(fmt.Sprintf("%s < %v (%v)", key, threshold, value))
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("NotificationBoard.NotifyLess %v (value < threshold): %v < %v : not found\n", key, value, threshold)
        // not found, started board as less
        n.notifier.Send(fmt.Sprintf("%s < %v (%v)", key, threshold, value))
    }

    n.Last.Store(key, value)
    return
}
```

I know that it should be enough using sync.Mutex OR sync.Map, but the code above has both, because it is my current (broken) version.

for testing, I set up the following code:

```
type dummy struct{}

func (d *dummy) Send(message string) {
    fmt.Println("--------------> notifying", message)
}

func newBoard() *NotificationBoard {
    notificationBoard := &NotificationBoard{}
    notificationBoard.Init(&dummy{})
    return notificationBoard
}
```

I also added a few fmt.Println traces (not included in my code above, for brevity) and the prepared a single-gouroutine test first (which works as expected):

```
func Test1(t *testing.T) {
    board := newBoard()
    board.NotifyLess("k1", 15, 10)
    board.NotifyLess("k1", 10, 10)
    board.NotifyLess("k1", 5, 10)
    board.NotifyLess("k1", 4, 10)
    board.NotifyLess("k1", 3, 10)
    board.NotifyLess("k1", 10, 10)
    board.NotifyLess("k1", 15, 10)
    board.NotifyLess("k1", 20, 10)
    board.NotifyLess("k1", 15, 10)
    board.NotifyLess("k1", 10, 10)
    board.NotifyLess("k1", 5, 10)
    board.NotifyLess("k1", 1, 10)
}
```

outputs:

```
> go test -run Test1
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess k1 (value >= threshold): 15 >= 10
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess k1 (value >= threshold): 10 >= 10
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess k1 (value < threshold): 5 < 10 : found 10
--------------> notifying k1 < 10 (5)
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess k1 (value < threshold): 4 < 10 : found 5
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess k1 (value < threshold): 3 < 10 : found 4
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess k1 (value >= threshold): 10 >= 10
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess k1 (value >= threshold): 15 >= 10
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess k1 (value >= threshold): 20 >= 10
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess k1 (value >= threshold): 15 >= 10
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess k1 (value >= threshold): 10 >= 10
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess k1 (value < threshold): 5 < 10 : found 10
--------------> notifying k1 < 10 (5)
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess k1 (value < threshold): 1 < 10 : found 5
PASS
```

we can see that the output "notifying ...." happens twice, only in the moments the sample falls below the threshold

but then, I created a multi-gouroutine test, and then notifications happen multiple times:

```
func Test3(t *testing.T) {
    preparing := sync.WaitGroup{}
    preparing.Add(1)

    board := newBoard()
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

    for i := 0; i < 30; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(x int, not *NotificationBoard) {
            fmt.Printf("routine %v waiting preparation... \n", x)
            preparing.Wait()

            for j := 15.0; j > 5; j-- {
                fmt.Printf("routine %v notifying %v\n", x, j)
                not.NotifyLess("keyX", j+float64(x+1)/100, 10)
            }

            wg.Done()
        }(i, board)
    }

    preparing.Done()
    wg.Wait()

}
```

which outputs:

```
> go test -run Test3
routine 7 waiting preparation...
routine 2 waiting preparation...
routine 2 notifying 15
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 15.03 >= 10
routine 2 notifying 14
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 14.03 >= 10
routine 2 notifying 13
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 13.03 >= 10
routine 2 notifying 12
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 12.03 >= 10
routine 2 notifying 11
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 11.03 >= 10
routine 2 notifying 10
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 10.03 >= 10
routine 2 notifying 9
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 9.03 < 10 : found 10.03
--------------> notifying keyX < 10 (9.03)
routine 2 notifying 8
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 8.03 < 10 : found 9.03
routine 2 notifying 7
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 7.03 < 10 : found 8.03
routine 2 notifying 6
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 6.03 < 10 : found 7.03
routine 14 waiting preparation...
routine 14 notifying 15
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 15.15 >= 10
routine 14 notifying 14
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 14.15 >= 10
routine 14 notifying 13
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 13.15 >= 10
routine 14 notifying 12
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 12.15 >= 10
routine 14 notifying 11
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 11.15 >= 10
routine 14 notifying 10
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 10.15 >= 10
routine 14 notifying 9
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 9.15 < 10 : found 10.15
--------------> notifying keyX < 10 (9.15)
routine 14 notifying 8
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 8.15 < 10 : found 9.15
routine 14 notifying 7
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 7.15 < 10 : found 8.15
routine 14 notifying 6
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 6.15 < 10 : found 7.15
routine 22 waiting preparation...
routine 27 waiting preparation...
routine 27 notifying 15
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 15.28 >= 10
routine 27 notifying 14
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 14.28 >= 10
routine 27 notifying 13
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 13.28 >= 10
routine 27 notifying 12
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 12.28 >= 10
routine 27 notifying 11
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 11.28 >= 10
routine 27 notifying 10
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 10.28 >= 10
routine 27 notifying 9
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 9.28 < 10 : found 10.28
--------------> notifying keyX < 10 (9.28)
routine 27 notifying 8
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 8.28 < 10 : found 9.28
routine 27 notifying 7
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 7.28 < 10 : found 8.28
routine 27 notifying 6
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 6.28 < 10 : found 7.28
routine 20 waiting preparation...
routine 20 notifying 15
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 15.21 >= 10
routine 20 notifying 14
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 14.21 >= 10
routine 20 notifying 13
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 13.21 >= 10
routine 20 notifying 12
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 12.21 >= 10
routine 20 notifying 11
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 11.21 >= 10
routine 20 notifying 10
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 10.21 >= 10
routine 20 notifying 9
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 9.21 < 10 : found 10.21
--------------> notifying keyX < 10 (9.21)
routine 20 notifying 8
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 8.21 < 10 : found 9.21
routine 20 notifying 7
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 7.21 < 10 : found 8.21
routine 20 notifying 6
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 6.21 < 10 : found 7.21
routine 19 waiting preparation...
routine 19 notifying 15
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 15.2 >= 10
routine 19 notifying 14
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 14.2 >= 10
routine 19 notifying 13
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 13.2 >= 10
routine 19 notifying 12
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 12.2 >= 10
routine 19 notifying 11
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 11.2 >= 10
routine 19 notifying 10
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 10.2 >= 10
routine 19 notifying 9
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 9.2 < 10 : found 10.2
--------------> notifying keyX < 10 (9.2)
routine 19 notifying 8
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 8.2 < 10 : found 9.2
routine 19 notifying 7
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 7.2 < 10 : found 8.2
routine 19 notifying 6
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 6.2 < 10 : found 7.2
routine 0 waiting preparation...
routine 0 notifying 15
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 15.01 >= 10
routine 0 notifying 14
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 14.01 >= 10
routine 0 notifying 13
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 13.01 >= 10
routine 0 notifying 12
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 12.01 >= 10
routine 0 notifying 11
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 11.01 >= 10
routine 0 notifying 10
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 10.01 >= 10
routine 0 notifying 9
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 9.01 < 10 : found 10.01
--------------> notifying keyX < 10 (9.01)
routine 0 notifying 8
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 8.01 < 10 : found 9.01
routine 0 notifying 7
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 7.01 < 10 : found 8.01
routine 0 notifying 6
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 6.01 < 10 : found 7.01
routine 17 waiting preparation...
routine 17 notifying 15
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 15.18 >= 10
routine 17 notifying 14
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 14.18 >= 10
routine 17 notifying 13
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 13.18 >= 10
routine 17 notifying 12
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 12.18 >= 10
routine 17 notifying 11
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 11.18 >= 10
routine 17 notifying 10
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 10.18 >= 10
routine 17 notifying 9
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 9.18 < 10 : found 10.18
--------------> notifying keyX < 10 (9.18)
routine 17 notifying 8
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 8.18 < 10 : found 9.18
routine 17 notifying 7
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 7.18 < 10 : found 8.18
routine 17 notifying 6
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 6.18 < 10 : found 7.18
routine 15 waiting preparation...
routine 16 waiting preparation...
...... continues
```

I added a decimal value to represent the goroutine, and looking to the output, it seemed that each goroutine had it's own copy of the map, since they were finding a previous value with the same decimal places. but then I found:

```
...
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 10.22 >= 10
routine 21 notifying 9
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 10.07 >= 10
routine 6 notifying 9
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 9.08 < 10 : found 10.07
--------------> notifying keyX < 10 (9.08)
routine 7 notifying 8
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 9.17 < 10 : found 9.08
routine 16 notifying 8
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value >= threshold): 10.11 >= 10
routine 10 notifying 9
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 9.3 < 10 : found 10.11
--------------> notifying keyX < 10 (9.3)
routine 29 notifying 8
NotificationBoard.NotifyLess keyX (value < threshold): 9.19 < 10 : found 9.3
routine 18 notifying 8
...
```

which shows that they were also finding previous values from other goroutines.

I'm pretty sure this is a basic concurrecy problem, but I could not spot it. :(

I'm using:

```
> go version
go version go1.10.2 windows/amd64
```

any ideias?

Comment: There's a lot of code to read and understand.  I suggest running the application with the race detector and reporting back.  It will be helpful to know if the code runs without races or if there is a race, where it's located.

Comment: I ran "go test -race" on that package and no data race was detected. the tests just "passed"

Comment: I'm not seeing the failure in your output... unless I'm just a little blind. The output you posted just seems to be goroutines that happen to be running sequentially. Which specific output shows a failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to simplify the logic here might be to run a single goroutine which modifies the map. Then, it could listen for new values on a channel (since it should be OK if values are processed sequentially). You'll need to be careful to know when your goroutine will return to make sure it doesn't leak. In general, you should not be sharing data between goroutines, you should be using channels to *communicate* between goroutines. https://gobyexample.com/channels is a good intro to channels. https://blog.golang.org/share-memory-by-communicating is a good explanation of the idiom, "Do not communicate by sharing memory; instead, share memory by communicating."

Here is an example of how you could implement this type of application using channels, rather than sharing memory ([playground version](https://play.golang.org/p/QQV8Oraa0Mm)).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type value struct {
    key       string
    value     float64
    threshold float64
}

func main() {
    b := board{
        last: map[string]float64{},
    }
    c := b.start()
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < 30; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int) {
            for j := 15.0; j > 5; j-- {
                c <- value{"k1", j + float64(i+1)/100, 10}
            }
            wg.Done()
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(c)
}

type board struct {
    last map[string]float64
}

func (b *board) start() chan<- value {
    c := make(chan value)
    go func() {
        for v := range c {
            b.notify(v)
        }
    }()
    return c
}

func (b *board) notify(v value) {
    if l, ok := b.last[v.key]; !ok || l >= v.threshold {
        if v.value < v.threshold {
            fmt.Printf("%s < %v (%v)\n", v.key, v.threshold, v.value)
        }
    }
    b.last[v.key] = v.value
}
```

Comment: fixed! also, I've noticed that my original test was kind of unfair. I started many goroutines with no delay, and so, sometimes, some routine got far behind the others, and sent samples higher that the threshold. I mean, my samples were not consistently monotonically decrescent in my test (causing noisy logs). anyway, I changed my implementation to use channels. thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set flags when you set such trackers, one for when value goes up and another for when value goes down. I implemented one

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

const (
    threshold      int = 10
    upperThreshold int = 20
)

var mu sync.Mutex
var downwatch bool
var upwatch bool

func main() {
    var tracker int = 10
    var temp int = 1
    var sign int = 1
    for i := 1; i < 20; i++ {
        sign = sign * -1
        temp = temp + i
        go UpdateTracker(&tracker, temp*sign)
    }

    for {
    }
    return
}
func SetDownWatch() {
    downwatch = true
}
func SetUpWatch() {
    upwatch = true
}
func UnSetDownWatch() {
    downwatch = false
}
func UnSetUpWatch() {
    upwatch = false
}

func UpdateTracker(tracker *int, val int) {
    mu.Lock()
    defer mu.Unlock()
    if !(upwatch || downwatch) {
        if (*tracker)+val < threshold {
            NotifyOnDrop()
            SetDownWatch()
        }
        if (*tracker + val) > upperThreshold {
            NotifyOnRise()
            SetUpWatch()
        }

    }
    if (*tracker)+val < threshold && upwatch {
        NotifyOnDrop()
        SetDownWatch()
        UnSetUpWatch()
    }

    if (*tracker+val) > upperThreshold && downwatch {
        NotifyOnRise()
        SetUpWatch()
        UnSetDownWatch()
    }

    *tracker = (*tracker) + val
    fmt.Println((*tracker))
    return
}

func NotifyOnDrop() {
    fmt.Println("dropped")
    return
}

func NotifyOnRise() {
    fmt.Println("rose")
    return
}
```

The `updateTracker` runs as a go routine and prints to console when the value crosses set threshold. I think that is the functionality you were looking for, what is missing here is the `Last.Store` function which I believe is custom to your code. I am sure there are other ways of handling this. This one seemed simple enough to me.